# Help understanding the two verbs in this sentence "...LURE Americans ... via tour groups RUN OUT OF China..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

In the last paragraph of the article [*North Korea Launches Tourism Site — Weeks After Jailed U.S. Tourist's Death*](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/07/20/538286261/north-korea-launches-tourism-site-weeks-after-jailed-u-s-tourists-death), it says,

> "The North Koreans **lure** Americans to travel to North Korea via tour groups **run out of** China, who advertise slick ads on the Internet proclaiming,

So, is North Korea trying to **lure** Americans or something different is **running out of** China? Did the writer make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**run [operated] out of China**   modifies **tour groups**; **run** is the passive past participle.  **out of China** complements **run**, identifying those who do the running (operating) indirectly via their location.

Compare:

> This is a website run by several fans of the rock star.
>   --Where is the website located?
>   It is run out of the UK somewhere.

A paraphrase for **to be run out of** a place might be "originating in" the place or "headquartered in" the place:

> When Apple first started up, the business was run out of a garage.